# SetParameter with IType doesn't result in meaningfull query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

If I do something like this:

```
  NHibernate.Type.IType type = NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.GetSerializable(myValueType);
  hibQuery.SetParameter("UserId", intObject, type);
```

`MyValueType` is of Type `Type`, representing `Int`. This doesn't result in something meaningfull. The sent SQL looks like this: `{...} where user0_.UserId=@p0;@p0 = 0x0001000000FFFFFFFF010000000000000004010000000C53797374656D2E496E74333201000000076D5F76616C75650008010000000B` (@p0 is not declared with something meaningfull)

If I do it that way (just for testing):

```
hibQuery.SetParameter<int>("UserId", (int)intObject);
```

the result would be just fine as expected: `{...}where user0_.UserId=@p0;@p0 = 1`

What am I doing wrong here?
sl3dg3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. The only thing I can think of is that intObject really isn't an Int32 (maybe it's actually an Int64 or an Int16 or even a Decimal, and the cast in the generic version hides the problem), or because it's "boxed" as an Object, serializing it as an Int32 without first casting it to an Int32 is causing some weird behavior. I would double-check that the type matches the actual type of the parameter.

If the type REALLY is correct for the object, and you really need the dynamic typing, try having NHibernate "guess" the type of the passed value. The runtime should always know the actual type of the object, so NH would be able to discover this without you specifying an IType (which may be wrong). If you're sure the type is right, you could also reflectively call the generic method that works in the test:

```
var setParamMethod = hibQuery.GetType().GetMethod("SetParameter`1");
setParamMethod.MakeGenericMethod(myValueType)
    .Invoke(nhibQuery, new object[]{"UserId", intObject});
```

Comment: It's strange, I double- and triple-checked the types, they are the same. Also thought there must be something wrong, but can't find anything. You are basically suggesting to simply call `hibQuery.SetParameter("UserId", intObject);` without the type-information? Well, I changed the code to this simplified solution and it seems to work so far...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you specifying the type explicitly?

This should work just as well:

```
.SetParameter("UserId", intObject)
```

Comment: I just wanted to make sure NHibernate will work internally with the correct type. But maybe it is really not necessary to define the type explicitly...

Comment: @sl3dg3: you only need to override the defaults when they are wrong.